# Button text needs to be changed as per EditText entered data

Tags: java, android, button, arraylist, android-edittext

I want to change the text of 4 buttons to the text entered in 4 EditText fields when fifth button is pressed.

I have created ArrayList for string and buttons. When I add components to the String ArrayList manually from EditText and then add it to setText() to Button ArrayList, it works just fine.

When I introduce another ArrayList for EditText fields and try to add its components to String ArrayList in a loop, the App crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button A,C,D,B;
    ArrayList<Button> options = new ArrayList<Button>();
    EditText P,Q,L,S;
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<EditText> typeText = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    public void changeButtonText(View view)
    {
      /*  answers.add(P.getText().toString());          /* works fine when 
        answers.add(Q.getText().toString());               this code is     
        answers.add(L.getText().toString());               run*/  
        answers.add(S.getText().toString());*/

        int j=0;

        for(j=0;j<3;j++)      /*creates problem when this loop is run */
        {
            answers.add(j,typeText.get(j).getText().toString());
        }

        j=0;
        for(Button i:options)
        {
            i.setText((answers.get(j)));
            j++;
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        P=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       Other EditText fields are declared the same way


        A=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       Other Buttons declare the same wat

        options.add(A);
        options.add(B);               //Add buttons to Button ArrayList
        options.add(C);
        options.add(D);

        typeText.add(P);
        typeText.add(Q);              //Add EditTexts to the ArrayList
        typeText.add(L);
        typeText.add(S);

    }
}
```

Text of the button changes when EditText ArrayList

Comment: Add the logs of the crash please

Comment: Use `for (j=0;j<typeText.size();j++)`

Comment: can you post proper code with error?
answers.add(S.getText().toString());*/  ------ this is not compilable

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for (int j=0;j<typeText.size();j++){
  answers.add(j,typeText.get(j).getText().toString());
}
```

instead of

```
for(j=0;j<3;j++)      /*creates problem when this loop is run */
        {
            answers.add(j,typeText.get(j).getText().toString());
        }
```